# Переименование проект в xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Подскажите как переименовать проект - точнее можно даже не весь проект, а только название в меню iphone и при открытии приложения надпись "ghfgfh". Если я в  xcode меняю название (в строке справа), то он мне даёт изменить названия, предлагает переименовать некоторые файлы, после чего вместо кнопки запуска приложения в симуляторе появляется шестеренка и не запустить проект

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понимаю, что у Вас xcode 6.3 или 6.3.1? 
В нем есть баг, при переименовании проекта xcode падает и портит проект. 
Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824737/xcode-6-3-1-crashes-while-renaming-project/29830678#29830678 обсуждали эту проблему. 
А так же можете посмотреть тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385542/project-crashes-after-rename

Думаю, что самый простой вариант, это откатиться на xcode 6.2. Либо можете так же посмотреть вот это решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692487/xcode-6-3-is-crashing-on-project-rename/29839390#29839390

Answer (score 0):

За подпись под иконкой отвечает параметр 'Bundle display name' в Info.plist

Его можно локализовать, добавив в проект файл InfoPlist.strings с содержимым:

> "CFBundleDisplayName" = "Название";